# How to speed up function optimization in scipy.optimize.minimize if function values are known at some points?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

The calculation of the function values takes a lot of time. But values of the multivariate function are known at some points. Is it possible to speed up the optimization algorithm (scipy.optimize.minimize with bounds) using this information?

Comment: sure add the known values to your initial guesses vector

Comment: @DrBwts But the initial guesses vector contains only independent variables (x). How can the function values (y) help?

Comment: depends on what is taking a lot of time, if the function or the algorithm, but most likely the answer is no. Usually you would want to: 1) change the solver method, 2) increase the tolerance, 3) Replace the function, for instance doing an ND grid interpolation and minimize the interpolator